# How to detect the code that babel has transformed ?

Tags: babeljs

For some dependencies. the source code has been transformed by babel or babel-loader. So these files don't need to transform again. But how to detect them ?

Comment: By "dependencies" you mean files in `node_modules`?

Comment: Generally you should be explicitly deciding what to run Babel on, and stuff in `node_modules` should already be ES5.